# program to find if two characters in String in a row are digits does not work in java

Tags: java, digits

I have the code below, which I want to take input from the keyboard and show me  if the input contains 2 digits in a row. If so, I want to get `false` printed out in the console, otherwise `true`. It works fine, except when the first 2 characters of the input are digits. In that case, I still get `true` in the console. Can anyone understand why? Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter:");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if (checkDigit(s)) {
            System.out.println("false");
        } else {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkDigit(String s) {
        boolean b = true;
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c[i]) && Character.isDigit(c[i + 1])) {
                b = true;
            } else {
                b = false;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: please spend more than one character for your variable names. You write code so that humans can read it. Thus you use names that have meaningf, helpful names.

Comment: Also your method should rather be named "hasTwoDigits" for example. That would make its usages easier to read as well.

Comment: Here's an advice. You should be using IDE like Eclipse to understand what's going wrong. If you have, use the 'Debug' mode.

Comment: You can use `charAt` in the loop instead of calling `toCharArray`. This avoids creating a new array. Also, you don't need to write `if (condition) { b = true; } else { b = false; }`: just write `b = condition;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You continue to check the input string even when you already found the result. As noted by [@Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske), you overwrite the value of the variable `b`, so your code will only return `true`, if the **last** two chars are digits.

You would need to return from the loop if there are two digits in a row:

```
 public static boolean checkDigit(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i < c.length-1; i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(c[i]) && Character.isDigit(c[i+1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

**UPDATE**: in fact there was an error in the snippet, as it was returning too early from the loop. Fixed now.

Comment: You forget to mention the actual problem, that he overwrites the value of b so that his code will only return true, if the last two chars are digits

Comment: @Stultuske First I thought that it's too obvious, but yeah, you are right, this should have been stated.

Comment: it may have been to obvious, but obviously not to the OP ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you overwrite the value on each loop iteration, so you only get true if the last pair of characters match. But [Krypt1 already said this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742616/3788176).

An alternative implementation using streams (because all the kids want to use Streams these days):

```
return IntStream.range(0, str.length()-1)
    .anyMatch(i -> Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

use **Character.isDigit(char)** method in your **if** condition and **return true;** rather than store b=true as that may get overwritten in next iteration.

you can also use regular expression. String's matches(pattern) method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}");
Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher("your input string");
```